# Function taxonomy based on contour topology

Tags: general-topology, surfaces

I only have a basic knowledge of topology so please correct any false assumptions. It seems that certrain functions have some similar (homotopic) contour curves, eg the gaussian and $-x^2$ have some homotopic contours around the global max. Has there been any research regarding such a taxonomy of n-ary functions? Is it even interesting?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing terribly sophisticated. Any $C^2$ function near a nondegenerate critical point will be locally like a quadric. See [Second partial derivative test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_partial_derivative_test). In the degenerate case, add higher order terms.